# CakePHP 3 - saving associated data with correct id

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I am fairly new to CakePHP, and am working on an event calendar.  The events can be single day events or multiple days, so I created an events table and a dates table.  When I save an event, the dates are saved in the Dates table as expected BUT the event_id field is always saved as 0 instead of the actual event id.

I think the relationships between the Events and Dates table is set properly.
This is what I have for the DatesTable:

```
    $this->table('dates');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Events', [
        'foreignKey' => 'event_id'
    ]);
```

This is my EventsTable:

```
    $this->table('events');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Dates', [
        'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

This is the code in my EventsController (WetKit is one of our plugins):

```
   $event = $this->Events->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $event = $this->Events->patchEntity($event, $this->request->data, [
            'associated' => 'dates'
        ]);

        if ($this->Events->save($event)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The form has been saved.'));
        } else
            $this->WetKit->flashError(__('The form could not be saved because error(s) were found.'), $event);
    }
```

How can I get the event id to save in the Dates table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The association on the `EventsTable` side is wrong, it should be either a `hasMany` (`1:n`) association, or a `hasOne` (`1:1`) association. Given that you're talking about multiple days, I'd assume that you're looking for the former.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)**

Comment: I changed the relationship to hasMany, but now it doesn't save anything at all in the Dates table.

Comment: @Juls79 I can't really help you with "_doesn't work_", without seeing the full picture, ie the association setup and ideally the data that you are trying to save, all I could do is shooting in the dark.

Comment: That's fine. I don't really know how to fix the issue, but you gave me something to read (linking tables together).  I'll look it up more thouroughly and hopefully will figure something out.  Thanks!